# NSRegularExpression weird behaviour

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Ive tried to figure this out for several hours and cannot find anything similar on the internets so hope you can help me out..

I'm trying to replace a single character in a NSString, should be quite simple right?
Here is what i've done:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *str1 = @"E bis the EVE E on E is the  the hte ee e.";
NSString *str2 = @"E abis the EVE E on E is the  the hte ee e.";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\bE\\b"
                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                       error:&error];


int numberOfMatches1 = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:str1
                                               options:0
                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length])];
int numberOfMatches2 = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:str2
                                               options:0
                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [str2 length])];
NSLog(@"%d, %d",numberOfMatches1,numberOfMatches2);

NSString *modifiedStr1 = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str1
                                               options:0
                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [str1 length])
                                               withTemplate:@"O"];

NSString *modifiedStr2 = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str2
                                               options:0
                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [str2 length])
                                               withTemplate:@"O"];

NSLog(modifiedStr1);
NSLog(modifiedStr2);
```

The idea is to replace all Single E's (also at the start and end of the string) with an O and leave all others as is.
In the first string this works as expected, but when I add someting to the string, in this case an 'a' on the 2nd position I get a false positive. 
The outputs are:

4, 5  (Nr of matches of str1 and str2)

O bis the EVE O on O is the  the hte ee O.   <--- correct

O abis the EVE O on O is the  thO hte ee O.  <--- false, it replaced the 'e' in 'the'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the compiler warnings - your two `int`'s should be `NSUInteger`, which in turn requires `%lu` in the format string, and the last two `NSLog` calls should have a format string - you are doing nothing wrong in the code you show and it works as expected (tested with Xcode 5.0.2 on 10.8.5).

So your problem is elsewhere. Step through the code in the debugger taking note of all the pointer values etc as you go and hopefully you'll find it.

Comment: Thanks CRD for the pointers. This was done on Linux with GNUStep. I tried it now in XCode and all works as expected...